# Visual Studio/IIS changes the order of Access file's table data

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I encountered weird problem when trying to use Access Database file in my project.

I have a table named 'CarGears'. When I add some rows to it, Visual Studio shows them at the start of the table, instead of putting it at the button.

I am including pics of the problem
[image]

[image]

Any solution for it?

Thanks

Comment: You could sort your query result?

Comment: Sure I can sort it via SQL query, but then I have to sort it every time I try to fetch data from this specific table. In other tables I don't have to do it...

Comment: If other tables are file, then what is the difference between them? Do you have an order specified in Access?

Comment: This is the only table where it happens. No Specified order. Everything as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access is in fact sorting the table by the primary key, and thus is ***IS*** sorting the data every time.

Most modern database systems consider all data un-ordered and you cannot assume order of data. The data is considered an un-ordered bucket of data. You can’t assume order since 5 users might be adding data, and now such order can’t be known since records can be added or removed by other users.

If you are using punched card computers, or reading a text file, you can assume order, but a database is not paper, not punched cards, and order of data can NEVER be assumed.

Bottom line:
If you want ordered data, then you query pull has to sort the data – any other assumption is NOT valid and cannot be assumed.

Access can sort 100,000 records with an index in about 1000th of a second or less – performance of such sorts is a non-issue, and even if it was, assumption of order cannot be assumed with a modern database system. This lesson and rule is usually the first day in any computer class that involves database theory.

You are doomed in the use of computers and data processing if you ignore the above simple fact of computers and how database systems work.

Comment: OK, this is what I have done at the end. But any explanation why it happens only in one table? other tables work perfectly.

Comment: That's it. You will never know. So always apply sorting if a certain order is expected.